# Django queries for database. Update if exists, insert if not exist

Tags: python, mysql, django

My table consists of two columns **url(address, count)**. I put this data in it. Data is in a tuple. And I what I need to do is:

**Search for same address in address field**

- if it's count is 5, then do count+5.
- Else if it doesn't exist cnt = count.

How do I write it in django ? This is what I wrote, but it does wrong:

```
    urls_tuple = [(url, urls_list.count(url)) for url in set(urls_list)]

    for (url, count) in urls_tuple:
        address, cnt = Url.objects.get_or_create(address=url)
        address.cnt = address.cnt + count
        address.save()
```

Comment: It looks fine. What output are you getting?

Comment: I think it is confusing to use the variable name `cnt` in this line: `address, cnt = Url.objects.get_or_create(address=url)` ...you should call it `created`

Comment: it may help to define your `cnt` field on the model with `default=0` to ensure there is always an integer value you can work with

Comment: Please paste the code of the `Url` model. It will help us get a better idea about the correctness of the code.